# How to change Bootstrap-select's placeholder color

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to change the placeholder/title color of [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) dropdown box. Right now it looks like this, which is black, I want it to be a dark grey.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPvWg.png)

I tried adding this to my css

```
span.filter-option.pull-left {
    color: darkgrey;
}
```

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFISO.png), which works fine. But this also made the options a dark grey instead of black. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk3Xu.png) I only want to change the color of the placeholder to dark grey not all the options. How do I best accomplish this? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<select name="box" class="selectpicker form-control">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="option1"> Option 1 </option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Pure CSS styling does not seem to work for me for some reason. I have tried using Bootstrap-select's native **title** property but it is not greyed out like it showed in the docs. Is there a Javascript/JQuery way for me to change the color of **span.filter-option.pull-left** depending whether it is "Select" or "Option 1"?

PS. this is what Chrome inspector tool shows me for [Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X0AU.png)
and for [Option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS6iC.png), there is no other option besides these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue at hand is that the plugin (bootstrap-select) doesn't really have a set way to do this.  If you're just using the single select (non-`multiple` attribute on the `select`) you can rely on the `bs-placeholder` class to be added when a value is selected,  which (if you're using LESS) uses the `@input-color-placeholder` variable to set the color:

```
.bootstrap-select {
  ...

  // The selectpicker button
  > .dropdown-toggle {
    ...

    &.bs-placeholder,
    &.bs-placeholder:hover,
    &.bs-placeholder:focus,
    &.bs-placeholder:active { color: @input-color-placeholder; }
  }
  ... 
}
```

The only problem with this is that the plugin doesn't add the class if it's a multiple select, so you have to get a little creative to determine if a value is selected.  Unfortunately the only DOM attribute manipulation that I can see happening by default is the title changing `.dropdown-toggle`.  If you don't mind hard coding the initial `title` attribute into the CSS, you can add a class that changes the color if the title is a certain value like so (https://jsfiddle.net/gxvqa5xa/):

```
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title=Select],
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title=Select]:hover,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title=Select]:focus,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title=Select]:active { color: darkgrey; }
```

Now, if that is too dirty or unreliable, the plugin does support event listeners, so you could just listen for change, check to see if it's blank and add a class if it is (I prefer this method):

```js
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
 $(this).prevAll('.dropdown-toggle').toggleClass('bs-placeholder', this.value === '');
}).trigger('changed.bs.select');
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/css/bootstrap-select.css);
*{outline:none !important;}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder:hover,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder:focus,
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder:active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<select name="box1" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Select">
  <option value="option1"> Option 1 </option>
  <option value="option2"> Option 2 </option>
  <option value="option3"> Option 3 </option>
</select>
<select name="box2" multiple class="selectpicker form-control" title="Select">
  <option value="option1"> Option 1 </option>
  <option value="option2"> Option 2 </option>
  <option value="option3"> Option 3 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know how bootstrap select work, but we do have attribute selectors in CSS, you can use them.
Something like

```
elements[attribute] {

}
```

*******EDIT 1********

After digging into BS-select, i found something like this

```
<select class="selectpicker" title="Choose one of the following...">
    <option>Mustard</option>

    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Which would place a brown color placeholder.

**** **EDIT 2*** *****

Working code

`button.bs-placeholder[role='button']>span{
     color:darkgrey;
}`

Comment: To change the color of the placeholder (when using the title attribute), you can simply add a style rule for the class `.bs-placeholder`

Comment: @JosephMarikle can you write an answer with that solution?

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion
`button.bs-placeholder [role='button'] > span {
    color: darkgrey;
}`

Comment: @TarunGarg thanks for some reason your solution does not work for me, but I did read the docs and this should work

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion Sorry, I didn't see that reply yesterday.  You litterally just have to use `.bs-placeholder { color:darkgrey; }`.  The class is removed after a real value is selected.  I didn't write it as a new answer because it's basically Tarun's answer with one tiny addition.  If Tarun doesn't, I'll just edit this answer to provide the correct style rule.  Also, if you're using Bootstrap SASS/LESS, `$input-color-placeholder` (`@input-color-placeholder` in LESS) is the variable `.bs-placeholder` uses to set the color.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I have tried doing .bs-placeholder { color:darkgrey; } but it is not getting picked up by the code at all

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion Oops! My bad.  The specificity is too high in the bootstrap-select stylesheet. `.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder` should work except on hover, active, and focus.  Also, it seems the plugin itself is a little inconsistent with the `bs-placeholder` class.  It doesn't add it when it's a multiple select: https://jsfiddle.net/vdsv8k9u/.  Probably the best way around this is to use an attribute selector: https://jsfiddle.net/svdydpzs/.  Obviously use LESS or SASS to simplify the rules.

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion Yeah, so it looks like it should just be this: https://jsfiddle.net/gxvqa5xa/.  `.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle[title=Select] {color:darkgrey !important;}` would work.  It's unfortunate that you have to hardcode the title value, but that's the limitation of the plugin itself.

Comment: @JosephMarikle thank you so much man this works! If you want to post your fiddle as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score -1):

1. Set different color for whole select tag.
2. Set normal color for all unchecked elements.

```css
select { color: red; }
option:not(:checked) { color: black; }
option:checked { color: black; }
```

```html
<select name="box" class="selectpicker form-control colored-title">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="option1"> Option 1 </option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ojdoug22/

edit:

```
option:checked { color: black; }
```

Just add this line to your CSS.

New JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ojdoug22/1/

edit2:
Added screenshot. I see red "title" select options and all others are black. If i select another one then it changes.
[image]

Comment: Your fiddle does not actually work? the two are the same color

Comment: Edited some css, try now.

Comment: Fiddle still does not show red. Also this is Bootstrap-select a custom plugin, maybe import it first?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: what browser are you using, in Chrome everything is always black, in FF everything is always red

Comment: Chrome: 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) and IE 11.545 - both works fine.